# How to get data between two date range in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I m querying data between two date range in PostgreSQL SQL but it does not give me expected result.

```
select
    pi_serial,
    amount_in_local_currency,
    status,
    proforma_invoice_date
from proforma_invoice
where created_by = 25
    and proforma_invoice_date BETWEEN '03/01/2018' and '09/03/2018'
order by proforma_invoice_date
```

[image]

Now look at the query and column proforma_invoice_date. In this query i am searching data between 03/01/2018 and 09/03/2018. the date format is (DD/MM/YYYY) and it's character varying. The result i have got in this picture. it just give me the result according by the only day but not the whole date format. i have tried so many things date conversion, character varying to date. but i didn't get any expected result

Comment: There is no need to add tags for nearly all Postgres version. If you want a version specific answer (because e.g. you are using an outdated or even unsupported version), then please only add a tag for **that** version

Comment: **NEVER**, ever store DATE values in a `varchar` column. Just don't. The reason your query isn't working is because of that wrong data type choice. You should convert it to a real `DATE` column.

Comment: Really you should consider change your data type.. If you are using varchar for date you can also insert lalala and it will give you problem... And you will lose the performance using date data type.. You can read this https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query is absolutely fine. just change it as follows

```
select pi_serial, amount_in_local_currency, status, proforma_invoice_date 
from proforma_invoice
where created_by = 25 
  and to_date(proforma_invoice_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  BETWEEN to_date('03/01/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date('09/03/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
order by proforma_invoice_date
```